# How to store string data into a single row in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
String = 'DOB; 04 March 1999; Passport; ABC123'
```

I have some data present in the above format.
I want to save it in a SQL table in a single row.
But only the date of birth and passport number present on second and fourth position.
Sometimes data can be changed like this:

```
String = 'DOB; March 04; Passport; 12345'
```

OR

```
String = 'DOB; March 04'
```

OR

```
String = 'Passport; ABC123'
```

What should be my approach? I have to do this using only SQL functions or queries.

I have tried different things like Stringsplit, cursor, parsename, substring, charindex etc but can't get the required result I need.

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max) = 'DOB;Mar 1199;Passport;W123333';
DECLARE @sep char(1) = ';'
    , @dot CHAR(1) = '.';
DECLARE @employee TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Dob1 varchar(20), 
    DobNum VARCHAR(20),
    Pass1 VARCHAR(20),
    PassNum VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Thanks in advance...

EDIT @Dale:

```
DECLARE @string3 varchar(max) = 'DOB; MARCH 1999; Passport; ABC123';
DECLARE @sep3 char(1) = ';'
DECLARE @dot3 char(1) = '.'
DECLARE @tab3 TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Dob1 varchar(max),
    Dobnum varchar(max),
    Pass1 varchar(max),
    Passnum varchar(max)
);

WITH QUERY1 as
(
    SELECT REPLACE(@string3, @sep3, @dot3) as ABClist
)
INSERT into @tab3 (DobNum,PassNum)
SELECT PARSENAME (ABCList,3),
        
        PARSENAME (ABCList,1)
        
FROM QUERY1

--TEST
select * from @tab3
select Dobnum, Passnum from @tab3


--cursor
declare 

@Dobnum2 varchar(max),

@Passnum2 varchar(max);

declare cursor3 CURSOR for

select Dobnum,Passnum from @tab3

OPEN cursor3;
FETCH next from cursor3 into
  @Dobnum2, @Passnum2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT  @Dobnum2 + @Passnum2

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]    
    (dobnum,passnum
    )
    values
    (  @Dobnum2, @Passnum2)

FETCH next from cursor3 into
  @Dobnum2, @Passnum2

END;
Close cursor3;
Deallocate cursor3;
```

Comment: Show us the table definition.

Comment: @jarlh Edited...

Comment: Please actually show us what you tried.

Comment: @Dale K: I have edited, please check

Answer (score 0):

The complicated part of your scenario is that the `DOB` and `Passport` substrings are not always at second and forth position. But, a JSON-based approach is a possible option here. You need to transform the input string into a valid JSON object with a specific structure (`DOB;Mar 1199;Passport;W123333` into `{"DOB":"Mar 1199","Passport":"W123333"}`) and parse the generated JSON using `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'DOB;Mar 1199;Passport;W123333';

INSERT INTO @employee (DobNum, PassNum)
SELECT DobNum, PassNum
FROM OPENJSON (CONCAT(
   '{"', 
   REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
            @String, 
            'DOB;', 
            'DOB":"'
         ), 
         'Passport;', 
         'Passport":"'
      ), 
      ';', 
      '","'
   ), 
   '"}'
   )
) WITH (
   DobNum varchar(20) '$.DOB',
   PassNum varchar(20) '$.Passport'
) j
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `STRING_SPLIT` and dynamic `pivot`

```
create table employee (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Dob1 varchar(20), 
    DobNum VARCHAR(20),
    Pass1 VARCHAR(20),
    PassNum VARCHAR(20)
);

create table temp(col varchar(20))
insert into temp 
select * FROM STRING_SPLIT('DOB; 04 March 1999; Passport; ABC123',';')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'insert into employee SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select col
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(col)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

***[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68b0f2cbe775ee2471b9b073333f330e)***

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw a different idea out there as well. One method would be to use a string splitter that provides the ordinal position (such as the JSON splitter I use here), to get the values into column name/column value pairs, and then use conditional aggregation to normalise, and `INSERT`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DSJ.[Position] % 2 = 0 THEN TRIM(DSJ.Item) END) AS ColumnName,
           MAX(CASE WHEN DSJ.[Position] % 2 = 1 THEN TRIM(DSJ.Item) END) AS ColumnValue
    FROM fn.DelimitedSplitJSON(@String,';') DSJ
    GROUP BY DSJ.[Position] / 2)
INSERT INTO @employee (DobNum, PassNum)
SELECT MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'DOB' THEN ColumnValue END),
       MAX(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'Passport' THEN ColumnValue END)
FROM CTE;
```

JSON splitter definition:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[DelimitedSplitNJSON] (@String nvarchar(MAX), @Delimiter nvarchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT [value] AS Item,
           [key] AS Position
    FROM OPENJSON(N'["' + REPLACE(@String,@Delimiter,N'","') + N'"]"');
```